# How to add animations to screens in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I am newbie into flutter. I have done the screen designs.
But, now my problem is to add `Animations` for the designed screens, Please help me out how do i achieve `Animations` for the screens. Help will be appreciated.

Have attached the below video for the reference..

https://filebin.net/8arfp9b6e1nhzrje/Screen1.mp4?t=741ossjz

Comment: Entity framework is not related tag

Comment: Okay, thanks
Please help me, how do i add animation for the screen as in video?

Answer (score 0):

There is no vide in that link , Can you please provide it for reference

Comment: Okay i will provide.

Comment: Here, below have added the reference video URLs
1. https://vimeo.com/user109082282/review/394358026/7786864486
2. https://vimeo.com/user109082282/review/394358062/d8bd0cac6b